# Have we really had 0 visitors per day?

Tags: bug, site-evaluation

The image below shows the site stats. We have a disappointing 0 visits per day.

I don't believe this is true though, as there has been activity, namely:

- Me visiting
- A question being on HNQ
- Questions being asked

So, **is the count correct?**

[image]

Comment: It's a known bug affecting several sites, it will be fixed (eventually).

Comment: [The main topic about this bug on general meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308966/traffic-views-visits-isnt-correctly-registered-on-site-analytics-or-area-51).